# Select last daily not null value with timezone

Tags: postgresql

I have a collection of data provided by many sensors and need to get the last value of the day per sensor at a specific timezone.

Every device is GEO-located so I need the day located accordingly.

Here's the involved table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.dt_weight(
  hive character(20) NOT NULL,
  hiveconnection integer,
  instant timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  weight integer,
  optweight integer,
  CONSTRAINT dt_weight_pkey PRIMARY KEY (hive, instant)
)
```

And the query:

```
SELECT w1.*
    FROM dt_weight w1
    JOIN (
        SELECT hive, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst') AS moment, 
            MAX(instant) AT TIME ZONE 'pst' AS last 
        FROM dt_weight 
        WHERE weight IS NOT NULL AND hive = '002C0055700833024E45' 
        GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst'), hive
    ) w2
    on (w1.instant = w2.last AND w1.hive=w2.hive)
WHERE w1.hive = '002C0055700833024E45' 
ORDER BY moment
```

and the result (hive, moment, last):

```
"002C0055700833024E45";932890;"2015-11-23 23:55:42+01";27800;
"002C0055700833024E45";933006;"2015-11-25 23:56:02+01";27770;
"002C0055700833024E45";933065;"2015-11-26 23:56:22+01";27610;
```

moment and last are returned as **timestamp without timezone** and many records are missing! Trying the subquery alone I get more values:

```
SELECT hive, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst') AS moment, 
    MAX(instant) AT TIME ZONE 'pst' AS last 
FROM dt_weight 
WHERE weight IS NOT NULL AND hive = '002C0055700833024E45' 
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst'), hive
ORDER BY last

"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 23:57:17"
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-19 00:00:00";"2015-11-19 23:58:12"
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-20 00:00:00";"2015-11-20 23:52:12"
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-21 00:00:00";"2015-11-21 23:53:03"
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-22 00:00:00";"2015-11-22 23:55:47"
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-23 00:00:00";"2015-11-23 23:55:42"
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-24 00:00:00";"2015-11-24 23:56:02"
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-25 00:00:00";"2015-11-25 23:56:02"
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-26 00:00:00";"2015-11-26 23:56:22"
```

Days 18 to 22 and 24 doesn't show up. Why?!? My client timezone is CEST. Need to mention that this query is meant as a piece of a bigger plan.

For completeness here's a slice of source data:

```
SELECT hive, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst') AS moment, instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst', weight
FROM dt_weight
WHERE weight IS NOT NULL AND hive = '002C0055700833024E45' 
ORDER BY instant

"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 03:04:57";3540
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 03:05:17";3540
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 06:47:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 06:57:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 07:07:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 07:17:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 07:27:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 07:37:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 07:47:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 07:57:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 08:07:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 08:17:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 08:27:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 08:37:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 08:47:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 08:57:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 09:07:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 09:17:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 09:27:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 09:37:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 09:47:27";0
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 09:57:27";27940
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 10:07:27";27940
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 10:17:27";27950
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 10:27:27";27960
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 10:37:27";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 10:47:27";27950
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 10:57:27";27950
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 11:07:27";27970
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 11:17:27";27960
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 11:27:27";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 11:37:27";27970
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 11:47:27";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 11:57:27";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 12:07:27";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 12:17:27";27970
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 12:27:27";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 12:37:27";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 12:47:27";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 12:57:27";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 13:07:27";27990
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 13:17:27";27990
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 13:27:27";27990
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 13:37:27";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 13:47:27";28020
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 13:57:23";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 14:07:23";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 14:17:23";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 14:27:23";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 14:37:23";27990
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 14:47:23";27990
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 14:57:23";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 15:07:23";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 15:17:23";27990
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 15:27:23";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 15:37:23";27990
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 15:47:23";28020
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 15:57:23";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 16:07:23";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 16:17:23";27960
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 16:27:23";27990
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 16:37:23";27990
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 16:47:23";27970
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 16:57:23";27990
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 17:07:23";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 17:17:23";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 17:27:23";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 17:37:23";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 17:47:23";27970
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 17:57:23";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 18:07:23";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 18:17:23";28030
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 18:27:23";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 18:37:23";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 18:47:23";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 18:57:23";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 19:07:23";28040
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 19:17:23";28030
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 19:27:23";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 19:37:23";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 19:47:23";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 19:57:23";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 20:07:23";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 20:17:23";27980
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 20:27:23";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 20:37:23";28040
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 20:47:23";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 20:57:17";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 21:07:17";28050
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 21:17:17";28020
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 21:27:17";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 21:37:17";28020
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 21:47:17";28020
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 21:57:17";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 22:07:17";28030
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 22:17:17";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 22:27:17";28030
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 22:37:17";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 22:47:17";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 22:57:17";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 23:07:17";28040
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 23:17:17";28020
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 23:27:17";28000
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 23:37:17";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 23:47:17";28020
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-18 00:00:00";"2015-11-18 23:57:17";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-19 00:00:00";"2015-11-19 00:07:17";28030
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-19 00:00:00";"2015-11-19 00:17:17";28010
"002C0055700833024E45";"2015-11-19 00:00:00";"2015-11-19 00:27:17";28010
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT ON (hive, moment)
    *, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst') AS moment
FROM dt_weight
ORDER BY hive, moment DESC, instant DESC;
```

It uses `DISTINCT ON` to keep only the first row for each combination of `hive` and day. To make sure that the first row that we keep is also the latest one, we additionally sort in reverse chronological order.

Comment: Well, this is one smart solution, thanks. I'm trying to put my other pieces altogether.