# Push dynamic parameter inside a join - cannot be referenced from this part of the query

Tags: postgresql

A table holds the timezoneID I need to use inside other joins but I get **cannot be referenced from this part of the query** error.
Is there a way to solve this issue?

The query is generated programatically so in the worse case I can recursively cycle all ID's but I would like, if possible, to achieve a view or something compiled and use more SQL than java.

Here is the query (related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750293/select-last-daily-not-null-value-with-timezone)):

```
WITH h AS (
    SELECT id, timez, 
        TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE '2016-05-1' AT TIME ZONE timez AS start,
        TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE '2016-05-5 23:59:59' AT TIME ZONE timez AS end,
        DATE_TRUNC('DAY', generate_series(
            TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE '2016-05-1' AT TIME ZONE timez, 
            TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE '2016-05-1' AT TIME ZONE timez + INTERVAL '4 DAYS',
            '1 day'
        ) AT TIME ZONE timez) AS moment 
    FROM hives
)
SELECT  id, h.moment, timez, t.internal_avg, t.external_min, t.external_max, w1.weight, w2.optweight
FROM h
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT hive, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst') AS moment, 
            AVG(internal)::integer AS internal_avg, MIN(external)::integer AS external_min, 
            MAX(external)::integer AS external_max
        FROM dt_temperature
        GROUP BY hive, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst')
    ) AS t ON (id=t.hive AND h.moment=t.moment)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (hive, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst')) 
            hive, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst') AS moment, weight
        FROM dt_weight
        WHERE weight IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY hive, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst') DESC, instant DESC
    ) AS w1 ON (id=w1.hive AND h.moment=w1.moment)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (hive, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst')) 
            hive, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst') AS moment, optweight
        FROM dt_weight
        WHERE optweight IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY hive, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE 'pst') DESC, instant DESC
    ) AS w2 ON (id=w2.hive AND h.moment=w2.moment)

WHERE id = '002C0055700833024E45' 
ORDER BY h.moment
```

I would like to use **h.timez** field instead of repeating everywhere **'pst'**.

**** EDIT - SOLUTION as suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name ****

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL(
    SELECT hive, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE timez) AS moment, 
        AVG(internal)::integer AS internal_avg, MIN(external)::integer AS external_min, 
        MAX(external)::integer AS external_max
    FROM dt_temperature
    WHERE instant >= start AND instant <= "end"
    GROUP BY hive, DATE_TRUNC('day', instant AT TIME ZONE timez)
) AS t ON (id=t.hive AND h.moment=t.moment)
```

Using LATERAL is possible to pass **timez** paramter as well as **start** and **end** and thus reduce the number of records processed by the JOINS (having **instant** indexed of course). 
Query runtime lowered from 243 to 21 msec

Comment: You want a `lateral` join

Comment: Yes! I added **start** - **end** into joins to reduce aperture and reduced the cost too